# How to get String from Mono<String> in reactive java

Tags: java, functional-programming, reactive-programming

I have a method which accepts Mono as a param.
All I want is to get the actual String from it. Googled but didn't find answer except calling block() over Mono object but it will make a blocking call **so want to avoid using block(). Please suggest other way if possible.**
The reason why I need this String is because inside this method I need to call another method say print() with the actual String value.
I understand this is easy but I am new to reactive programming.

Code:

```
public String getValue(Mono<String> monoString) {
    // How to get actual String from param monoString
    // and call print(String) method
}

public void print(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: could you explain to me what Mono is?

Comment: check -> http://musigma.org/java/2016/11/21/reactor.html

Comment: If you use the block(Duration timeout) with zero duration -
 https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block-java.time.Duration-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally what worked for me is calling flatMap method like below:

```
public void getValue(Mono<String> monoString)
{
   monoString.flatMap(this::print);
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, instead of creating your own `print(String str)` method and doing `this::print`, you can simply do `System.out::print`

Comment: Why does this exact piece of code gives me an error: "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Mono<? extends R>>)" ??

Comment: This gives me the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492668/to-take-a-string-from-a-fluxstring-throws-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-d)

Comment: does this answer provide any extra information other than Alexey Romanov's?

Answer (score 64):

Getting a `String` from a `Mono<String>` without a blocking call isn't easy, it's impossible. By definition. If the `String` isn't available yet (which `Mono<String>` allows), you can't get it except by waiting until it comes in and that's exactly what blocking is.

Instead of "getting a `String`" you `subscribe` to the `Mono` and the `Subscriber` you pass will get the `String` when it becomes available (maybe immediately). E.g.

```
myMono.subscribe(
  value -> System.out.println(value), 
  error -> error.printStackTrace(), 
  () -> System.out.println("completed without a value")
)
```

will print the value or error produced by `myMono` (type of `value` is `String`, type of `error` is `Throwable`). At https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html you can see other variants of `subscribe` too.

Comment: That's what I am looking for-> how to subscribe it? May be via lambda?

Comment: Yes, that's one option. See the edit. But the point is that you can't write `getValue` method in your question.

Comment: Actually with string value I need to call another method... Let's say Mono<string> myMono has "abc"  as actual string. With that String I need to call another method say print(String str) in that method. So how do I achieve it.. myMono.subscribe(value->print(value)) ?

Comment: Yes, just as I show with `Console.out.println` in the example.

Comment: What is Console.out.println? Shouldn't it be System.out.println?

Comment: @Kingamere Yes, not sure what I confused it with.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [doc](http://musigma.org/java/2016/11/21/reactor.html) you can do:

```
String getValue(Mono<String> mono) {
    return mono.block();
}
```

be aware of the blocking call

Comment: I know usage of block but as it will make a blocking call I don't want to use it. Isn't there another way?

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was the following:

`monoString.subscribe(this::print);`

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer is:

```
 String returnVal = mono.block();
```

Comment: But it blocks the call

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
String str = monoString.toProcessor().block();
```

Comment: I think this is now deprecated

Answer (score -1):

Better

```
monoUser.map(User::getId)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21564390)

Comment: What's User, monoUser and getId? None of them are in original question. So all you are trying is to solve an hypothetical query.

Comment: This will return a Mono back with the value of the ID --> Mono<Integer> if the id is Integer. I think the question was to return a String and not a Mono