# Check if Document in MongoDB exists, using reactive-streams

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive-streams

I'm trying to check if a document already exits, but I'm having some problems.
I tried different solutions:

1. Using `findOne()` and checking if output is `null` (doesn’t work)
2. Using `countDocument()` (doesn’t work)
   The error that is saw the most is that I can’t cast for example: `Publisher` to `long` or `Publisher` to `Document`

Thanks.

Method 1:

```java
Document d = collection.find(eq("UUID", id)).first();
if (d == null) {
    System.out.println("document = null");
    return;
}
System.out.println("document exists");
```

Method 2:

```java
if (collection.countDocuments(query) < 1) {
    System.out.println("Document exists");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a document exists you can use the `exists()` method from the `ReactiveMongoTemplate` class. The method takes a `Query` object as its parameter, which is used to specify the conditions to match the document. You can read about the `exists()` method right [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html#exists(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,java.lang.Class)).

Here is an example of how you can use the `exists()` method to check if a document with a specific `id` field exists in a collection called `docs`:

```java
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is("unique-id-123"));
Mono<Boolean> exists = reactiveMongoTemplate.exists(query, “docs”);
```

Where `query` is  `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` and `reactiveMongoTemplate` is `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate`

---

Another solutions that you mentioned actually have to work too, for example:

1. Using `findOne()` method:

```java
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is("unique-id-123"));
Mono<Document> documentMono = reactiveMongoTemplate.findOne(query, Document.class, "docs");
documentMono.subscribe(doc -> {
    if (doc != null) {
        System.out.println("Document exists!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Document does not exist!");
    }
});
```

You can read about `findOne()` method [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html#findOne(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,java.lang.Class)).

**Update for [1]: findOne()**:

As [kerbermeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14183092/kerbermeister) mentioned, That approach will not work:

> reactor does not allow null values, so if publisher completes with empty, there will be no null value

and

> When Publisher completes with empty it instantly completes with onComplete signal, not onNext. Also, as documentation of subscribe(Consumer) suggests: consumer – the consumer to invoke on each value (onNext signal). So this callback will never be called if publisher completes with empty.

2. Using `count()` method:

```java
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is("unique-id-123"));
Mono<Long> count = reactiveMongoTemplate.count(query, "docs");
count.subscribe(cnt -> {
    if (cnt > 0) {
        System.out.println("Document exists!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Document does not exist!");
    }
});
```

You can read about `count()` method [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html#count(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,java.lang.Class))

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! Unfortunately, I get an error message within my IDE with 'Mono': Cannot access reactor.core.publisher.Mono

Comment: Fixed it. I didn't imported the reactor api, only the springframework. But how do I cast Mono<Boolean> to boolean?

Comment: @Jackolix you can use `subscribe()`, or `block()` methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179937/how-to-get-string-from-monostring-in-reactive-java

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo "another" solution 1 would not work, reactor does not allow null values, so if publisher completes with empty, there will be no null value

Comment: @kerbermeister Thank you. Have you check that? If it is so, I'll update my answer

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo of course. When Publisher completes with empty it instantly completes with onComplete signal, not onNext. Also, as documentation of subscribe(Consumer) suggests: consumer – the consumer to invoke on each value (onNext signal). So this callback will never be called if publisher completes with empty.